# How to add a property when building a new array of objects using Javascript .reduce, as opposed to .filter().map()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, javascript-objects, reduce

I have code that is successfully working using **.filter().map()** but I would like to rewrite it using **.reduce()** so as to use only *one* iteration, as opposed to the two in the former case.

Let's say we have an array of Fruit Objects...

```js
var fruitArray = [
{name: 'Apple', color: 'red'}, 
{name: 'Banana', color: 'yellow'}, 
{name: 'Kiwi', color: 'green'}, 
{name: 'Blueberry', color: 'blue'}, 
{name: 'Orange', color: 'orange'}
]
```

And we want

1. A new array that is a subset or filter of that set of fruit.
   (e.g. we can say we want "Fresh Fruit"... assume we have a function, *isFresh*, that determines this condition)
2. We want each fruit in this new array to have a new property (or key-value pair) added to it, represented by foo: 'bar'.

I was able to do this in a fairly straightforward way with **.filter()** and **.map()** :

```js
var freshFruit = fruitArray.filter(fruit => isFresh(fruit)).map((fruit) => {
      const value = 'bar'
      return {...fruit, foo: value }
    });

console.log(freshFruit);

/*
[
  { name: 'Apple', color: 'red', foo: 'bar' },
  { name: 'Kiwi', color: 'green', foo: 'bar' },
  { name: 'Blueberry', color: 'blue', foo: 'bar' }
]
*/
```

When I try to do this with reduce

```js
var freshFruit = fruitArray.reduce((previousValue, fruit)=>{
        if (isFresh(fruit)) {
          const value = 'bar'
          fruit.foo = value
          previousValue.push(fruit);
        }
          return previousValue;
    }, []);
```

I get the desired output for freshFruit, but then I notice that it also edits my original fruitArray

```js
console.log(fruitArray);

/*
[
  { name: 'Apple', color: 'red', foo: 'bar' },
  { name: 'Banana', color: 'yellow' },
  { name: 'Kiwi', color: 'green', foo: 'bar' },
  { name: 'Blueberry', color: 'blue', foo: 'bar' },
  { name: 'Orange', color: 'orange' }
]
*/
```

Notice how the reduce added the foo property.

**...**

Going through the process of typing this out, I may have solved my own problem.

I think I need to use the spread operator in the reduce function

```js
var freshFruit = fruitArray.reduce((previousValue, fruit)=>{
    if (isFresh(fruit)) {
        const value = 'bar'
        previousValue.push({...fruit, foo: value});
    }
        return previousValue;
    }, []);
```

So this could still be a question with an answer, let me ask this

1. **Why is this spread syntax necessary? Why didn't my first attempt with the .reduce() method work?** I can see now, in hindsight, why it shouldn't work, but I think I was stuck on the idea that reduce creates a temporary state/variable as opposed to live editing the existing variable.
2. **Are there material performance benefits from using .reduce() instead of .filter().map()? Should this be a general recommendation to anyone who is tempted to use a .filter().map()?**

Comment: JavaScript never makes copies of objects automatically, they're always passed by reference to the original object. If you want a copy, you have to do it explictly.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. You thought you would get a copy, but now understand that you don't.

Comment: "*Are there material performance benefits from using .reduce() instead of .filter().map()?*" - no, not at all. If you wanted a performance benefit, just use a plain loop instead of `reduce` with all the unnecessary accumulator assignments and function calls, it also is much cleaner. But the difference won't be large enough to matter, you should focus on clarity, where `filter().map()` wins. If you really cared about performance, the only way to know for sure is to [measure yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)!

Answer (score 2):

> Are there material performance benefits from using `.reduce()` instead of `.filter().map()`? Should this be a general recommendation to anyone who is tempted to use a `.filter().map()`?

I wouldn't worry too much about the overhead of iterating twice, as iteration is a very simple process. However, if the arrays are large, using `.filter().map()` means that an extra temporary array needs to be created to hold the result of `.filter()` before it can start mapping. This could be a significant amount of memory, and having to go back to the beginning for the `.map()` has poor cache locality.

However, in my opinion `reduce()` is usually harder to write and understand than `filter()` and `map()`. So unless performance is critical, I prefer to use `.filter().map()`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Why didn't my first attempt with the .reduce() method work?**

I just repeated your code and it works fine, check this example.

You log the original `fruitArray` array instead of the processed `freshFruit` array

```js
const fruitArray = [
    {name: 'Apple', color: 'red'}, 
    {name: 'Banana', color: 'yellow'}, 
    {name: 'Kiwi', color: 'green'}, 
    {name: 'Blueberry', color: 'blue'}, 
    {name: 'Orange', color: 'orange'},
];

const isFresh = ({ name }) => 
  ['Apple', 'Kiwi', 'Blueberry'].includes(name);
  
const result = fruitArray.reduce((previousValue, fruit)=>{
    if (isFresh(fruit)) {
      const value = 'bar'
      fruit.foo = value
      previousValue.push(fruit);
    }
      return previousValue;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, another "hacky-one-liner" way of mapping and filtering with `.flatMap`:

```js
const fruitArray = [
    {name: 'Apple', color: 'red'}, 
    {name: 'Banana', color: 'yellow'}, 
    {name: 'Kiwi', color: 'green'}, 
    {name: 'Blueberry', color: 'blue'}, 
    {name: 'Orange', color: 'orange'},
];

const isFresh = ({ name }) => 
  ['Apple', 'Kiwi', 'Blueberry'].includes(name);
  
const result = fruitArray.flatMap((fruit) => 
  isFresh(fruit) ? { ...fruit, foo: 'bar' } : []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```